# In LMDB, how to nest one RW transaction within another RW transaction? What is the practical usecase/application of nesting transactions in LMDB?

Tags: transactions, lmdb

On page: http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/starting.html

§1

> Transactions may be read-write or read-only, and read-write transactions may be nested.

§2

> There can be multiple simultaneously active read-only transactions but only one that can write. Once a single read-write transaction is opened, all further attempts to begin one will block until the first one is committed or aborted. This has no effect on read-only transactions, however, and they may continue to be opened at any time.

**So, how can an RW transaction be made a parent of another RW transaction if only one RW txn can exist within an lmdb environment at a time?**

---

References:

1. The txn handle constructor, [mdb_txn_begin(...)](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#gad7ea55da06b77513609efebd44b26920), takes an optional txn handle to make it a parent of the would-be transaction. So an [MDB_txn](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__internal.html#structMDB__txn) instance, say a `parent-txn-handle`, is needed beforehand, to provide to `mdb_txn_begin`, to make the `parent-txn-handle` a parent of a `would-be-child-txn-handle`.
2. from: [nested transactions doc, for BerkeleyDB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/gsg_txn/C/nestedtxn.html) because lmdb's doc doesn't contain elucidation of nested lmdb txn semantics.

   > A nested transaction is used to provide a transactional guarantee for a subset of operations performed within the scope of a larger transaction. Doing this allows you to commit and abort the subset of operations independently of the larger transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the references you included answer your questions for the most part.

As explained, when you create a nested transaction, you need to pass a handle to the parent transaction to `mdb_txn_begin`. The "one write transaction at a time" restriction does not apply to a parent transaction's children transactions.

You can commit or abort the effects of a child transaction without committing or aborting the parent's. If you commit then the changes become part of the parent transaction's changes (not yet visible to the outside world). The parent transaction must then commit for the changes to be saved.

As your BDB reference describes, this can be useful if you want to do multiple independent units of work in a single transaction (possibly for performance reasons). You can open a parent transaction and then do each unit of work in its own child transaction. If there is a failure in a unit of work, you can roll it back without effecting the other units of work, and then proceed to process the remainder. When you finally commit the parent, only the successful units will be applied to the DB.

Comment: so does it mean that, after creating one RW txnA, i can create another RW txnB if I make it a child of another RW txn itself. so I can create an RW txnA but not another RW txnB outside it. however, creation of another RW txn is possible when that another txnB is made a child of a txn which is itself RW.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, be aware that child transactions are pretty much only useful for the "independent units" use-case I described above. The parent transaction cannot be used until the child transaction commits/aborts, so you cannot use this to do 2 write operations in parallel, for example.